# How do I break up my glue code into multiple files?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm starting to build out my glue job however I'd like to add a custom logger (and other files) to it so that it's cleaner code. How do i break up my files and re import them into the glue job. Say a `main.py`, `utils.py` and `logging.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is included [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html):
In terraform you zip up your modules and an `__init__.py` file and deposit them in s3. You then add their location in s3 in the `--extra-py-files` argument.
In terraform you have an argument available to you:

```
"--extra-py-files"            = "s3://${aws_s3_object.foo.bucket}/${aws_s3_object.foo.key},s3://${aws_s3_object.barr.bucket}/${aws_s3_object.barr.key}"
```